# Dynamic menu through use of repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, repeater

I am using a repeater to create a menu (Bootstrap styled). I need to initially make the first item active and can't figure out how. This is what I have:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul id="teamTab" class="nav nav-pills pill-marg" role="tablist">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMenu">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a class="circular" href='#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupAbbrev") %>' aria-controls="home"
                        role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%# String.Format("{0}", Eval("GroupName").ToString().ToUpper()) %></a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

To make the first menu item active, its style has to be "active", like:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a class="circular" ...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add `<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active circular" : "circular" %>` inside your repeater template (however its been **years** since I have used WebForms.

Example:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul id="teamTab" class="nav nav-pills pill-marg" role="tablist">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMenu">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li role="presentation" class="<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "" %>">
                <a class="circular" href='#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GroupAbbrev") %>' aria-controls="home"
                        role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%# String.Format("{0}", Eval("GroupName").ToString().ToUpper()) %></a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Syntax issues aside (if I have any), I *know* the index is available via `ItemIndex`, see the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. But it is the <li> that either has a class "Active" or no class at all, not the <a element. Also, would this result in first item being active all the time? When another menu item is clicked, it becomes active and first one becomes inactive (no class).

Comment: @NoBullMan my bad, I put the logic in the anchor tag.  I updated my answer (sounds like you already figured it out though)